# Android | Youtube Live Streaming

Tags: android, youtube, rtmp, http-live-streaming, android-youtube-api

I need to play Live streaming from Youtube channel into my android app.

Here is my RTMP Url   - `rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2`
And i also have `Stream Key`
Can someone please help me or guide me on this.

It would be really great if someone suggest me how to achieve this.

**EDIT**

I have integrated Youtube in my app, but when i play any live channel then it shows me below logs -

```
E/YouTubeAndroidPlayerAPI: fmt.noneavailable
                                                          ouq: Video not supported/available
                                                              at oun.a(SourceFile:217)
                                                              at oqa.a(SourceFile:384)
                                                              at oqa.a(SourceFile:710)
                                                              at oqg.a(SourceFile:1143)
                                                              at onp.onPostExecute(SourceFile:2102)
                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                              at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                              at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5930)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1405)
                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1200)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by following code -

```
        //Opens in the StandAlonePlayer, defaults to fullscreen
        startActivity(YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(SplashScreen.this,
                DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID));
```